# Regenerate auto excerpts after updating many posts

Tags: excerpt

I had around 100 posts that I imported into my blog. Many of the special characters (e.g. apostrophes, etc) were mangled upon import. I finally went through and fixed them all manually by editing each post and updating it. My theme displays the automatic excerpt of each post on the front page and these have NOT updated. My question is: How can I get WordPress to regenerate the automatic excerpts for all the posts? I'm using 3.5.2 and my theme is using "the_excerpt();" template tag to display these. I haven't used the manual excerpt field to make any of these excerpts.

Comment: Are there any filters on `get_the_excerpt`? Do you have any caching mechanisms on the site? It sounds like your theme or a plugin has altered default behavior. Disable your plugins and switch themes to try to isolate the code repsonsible.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum - that's exactly what it was. I guess that during the "import" excerpts were created and stored in the database. My theme didn't show these (even with the excerpt panel shown in the edit post page). When I changed the theme to twentytwelve, all the excerpts with the mangled characters showed up in the edit post page. This allowed me to delete the excerpts. Once this was done, I reactivated my theme and voila, the automatic excerpts appeared with all the correct characters.

Comment: If your theme is creating some kind of static, hidden excerpt you are likely to have this problem again. I would not stop at this workaround.

Comment: Thank you again. I guess the importer actually created the excerpts, because now, there are no excerpts in any of the posts, even if I switch to the twenty twelve theme. I agree though that fixing the symptoms isn't as elegant or permanent as fixing the problem. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I know it's been a while but feel free to turn your comment into an answer.